# Use of Boltzmann over Maxwell distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Why is the Boltzmann distribution used over the Maxwell distribution in many cases such as the derivation of Plancks law of thermal radiation, derivation of Einstein A and B coefficients, Langevin theory of paramagnetism etc.?

Comment: I am not sure to completely understand your question, but you always apply the  Boltzmann in a system at constant temperature (canonical ensemble), $p \propto e^{-\frac{E}{kT}}$. The difference in the practical applications, is then in the possible values of the energy $E$, and in the expression of the density of states $g(E)$.

Comment: My doubt arises because in the Maxwell distribution the term of dE contains an extra factor of sqrt(E) in multiplication to the exponential term.

Comment: The density of states may be expressed as a function of $E$ or a function of $v$ (the speed modulus). We have :  $g(E) dE = g(v) dv$, with $g(v) \sim v^2$. Now $E \sim v^2$, so finally, you have $g(E) \sim \frac{dv}{dE} g(v) \sim \frac{1}{v} v^2\sim v \sim \sqrt{E}$

Comment: Exactly,now if you factor this in the derivation for the above laws, they dont quite match.

Comment: There is no problem : the probability $p = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\frac{E}{kT}}$ concerns a probability for one microstate of energy $E$. Now, if you look at the probability of the whole set of  microstates having energy $E$, which we can call the "macrostate $E$", the probability of this macrostate is equal to the density of (micro)states $g(E)$ multiply by the probability of one microstate of energy $E$, so you have : $p_{macrostate \, E} \, \, dE= g(E) \times p_{microstate \, E} \, \,dE$